# Is it OK to dress casually if someone is going on a hike on Chol Hamoed?

Tags: clothing, chol-hamoed

I'm pretty sure there is a thing about still dressing nicely on Chol Hamoed, but what if someone wants to go on a hike? Is it considered bad to dress in shorts and a T-shirt in such a situation? Because it may be a bit awkward to hike in Shabbat clothing.

Comment: This question has the risk of being closed because it is asking a psak halacha here. Please edit your question to make it more theoretical.

Comment: Shmuel I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: The Mishna Berura writes ם חייב לכבד חוה"מ במאכל ובמשתה וכסות נקיה שלא ינהג בהן מנהג חול. 
 so a nice T Shirt would be Kavod Yom Tov.

Comment: Because see: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi